# How can I pipe data over network or serial to the display of another linux machine?

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, netcat

I have a second monitor that I'd like to use for a text-based debugging log and/or console. I don't want to have it as part of my GUI / "desktop" / main system.

I have this display connected to an old linux box that doesn't have much processing power. When it boots up it sits ready at the `login:` prompt.

It is connected to the LAN so I can SSH to it. I know I can write to the screen by running something like `ssh root@ancient echo test \> /dev/tty0`

I enjoy using named pipes for debugging, basically creating one named pipe with `mkfifo` and then using `tail -f` on it while writing data to it from other commands / scripts / etc.

#### Based on this explanation of what I'm attempting to do, what is a "good" / "right" way to do what I'm trying to do ("dump data" to a named pipe over the network so that the output would appear on this terminal's screen? )

I know I've got access to `ssh`, `tail`, netcat (`nc`), and redirection via things like `/dev/tty0` - but I can't quite figure out how to put it all together eloquently. I did see this: [Can I pipe/redirect a console application through netcat so it can be used remotely?](https://superuser.com/questions/607783/can-i-pipe-redirect-a-console-application-through-netcat-so-it-can-be-used-remot)

It seems hackish to use something like `ssh root@ancient echo test \> /dev/tty0` and create a new connection for every log item that gets sent.

A bonus would be if the data was not sent over the network as plain-text, but I suppose that criterion is not mandatory if it makes things very slow or creates too much overhead or complication.

#### Also,  would there be any advantage in using a serial connection between the two machines instead?

I have done this in the past but it seemed to me that even at the maximum baud rate of `115,200` that when a few hundred lines of code were sent it seemed 'laggy' compared to sending the data over the network. I know `115k` is old "modem technology" so I just wanted to know if this slower-than-expected experience for this type of direct ( albeit serial) connection is normal.

Comment: Is there a reason that `tail -f fifo | ssh root@ancient cat \> /dev/tty0` doesn't work for you? I'm inferring that it doesn't but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - thanks, that seems to work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

netcat springs to mind; it may be the more sensible choice (given the no-overhead, no compression approach to network communications) on your low-spec receiving machine.

A nice usage example can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113986/example-of-using-named-pipes-in-linux-bash

Comment: That might be the solution. Let me do some testing and I will be back to select this as the solution if I have some luck. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tail -f` the way you're accustomed to, and pipe that across an `ssh` connection to the other machine:

```
tail -f fifo | ssh root@ancient cat \> /dev/tty0
```

You run `cat > /dev/tty0` on the other side, which will echo its input back out onto the terminal. `ssh` will pass the output from `tail` into the standard input of `cat` across the network. All the data is fully encrypted in transit

A serial connection would work, but unless one of the machines is very weak the overhead of `ssh` and network traffic will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

it should be enough using

```
cat > /dev/udp/ancient/12345
```

on one machine and

```
nc -lu 12345
```

on the other. If you want to use TCP for reliability just remove the `-u` option from `nc` and replace `/udp/` with `/tcp` on the redirection

Comment: Well, there is no /dev/dcp or /dev/udp folder in the file system. At least not on Arch linux.

Comment: @Arne they are special pseudo-devices on linux (see https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html)